# manage the css style for image after print preview in chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, print-preview

I have an html page where we have images,text and two buttons

1.print page for printing the page

2.Hide/Show(toggle button) for hide/show below the image.

image in the page are generated dynamically using remote service.

In Google-Chrome
When I click Hide/Show button to hide image and click print button,print preview page comes on the same page. 
Then I cancel print page and back to page.
Then I again click Hide/Show button to show image

here the problem is that image is not shown on the page.

Using firebuglite I found that inline css style like width and height for image are 0 and hence image is not shown on the page.
How can I manage the css style for image after print preview and this problem occurs only in Chrome.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

here is CSS Browser Selector using javascript:
http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/
you can use that,then add the class:

```
.chrome #btn{
height:30px !important;
width:100px !important;
}
```